# Does Azure AD Temporary Access Pass work on Hybrid Join

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I have setup Temporary access pass, conditional access, temporary access authentication method and web sign in. I am only able to get this to work if I logon through a Azure AD joined computer. If I try this on a Hybrid Joined Computer it does not work. Is this supposed to work on a Hybrid joined computer?